# Differing solutions with the reduction of order method

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

In the following differential equation:

$$(1-x^2)y''+2xy'-2y = 0\space\space(-1 < x < 1);\space y_{1}(x)=x $$

I used the method of **reduction of order** to find a second linearly independent solution, y<sub>2</sub>.

The solution I found was:

$$ y_{2}(x)= -1-x^2 $$

However, this is the given solution within the text book I was referring to:

$$ y_{2}(x)= 1+x^2 $$

I understand that technically my solution is correct. However, how do I use the reduction order method to arrive at the solution y<sub>2</sub>(x) = 1 + x<sup>2</sup> ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any solution like $c_1(x^2+1)$ is a solution. You can choose $c_1=1$ or $c_1=-1$. The solution to this homogeneous DE is:
$$y(x)=c_1(x^2+1)+c_2x$$